# Flutter make pop animation with same duration as push

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, push, transition

I am using `Hero` and a `PageRouteBuilder` to navigate with animations between two screens. The problem is that my `pop` animation is way shorter than my `push` and that looks a bit clunky. Here is a [ScreenVideo](https://gofile.io/d/Mr5mV2) for a better understanding.

That is how I build my `push`:

```
static PageRouteBuilder _buildTransitionToMonthPage(Month month) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return MonthPage(
          month: month,
        );
      },
      transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And on the other Screen I simply call `Navigator.pop(context)`. What am I missing here? Shoudn't it simply reverse the animation duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageRouteBuilder-class.html) for `PageRouteBuilder`, for the property `transitionDuration` it says: *"The duration the transition going **forwards**."* Initially, it is set to 300ms duration (Check source code).

> this.transitionDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300)

Additionally there is a `reverseTransitionDuration` property which states: *"The duration the transition going in **reverse**."* Initially its value is the same as `transitionDuration`

> this.reverseTransitionDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300),

**Why are you facing this issue?**

You have provided the forward transition as 1000ms whereas reverse transition is still 300ms. So, adding `reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(1000)` will resolve your issue.